# Tests with Quick and Nimble

Tags: ios, swift, testing, bdd

I installed Quick and Nimble frameworks for tests in Swift. But inside test class my class' types is unresolved. In the top of test class I make imports:

```
import UIKit
import Nimble
import Quick
import MyProject
```

I know my main target should be at target dependencies and no classes files (except test classes) should be added to compile sources of test target.

Why my files is not visible in test target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your classes as `public`. Otherwise, you won't see anything from your test bundle

Also, the default access level of every property/ function is just its own target. So you also need to declare them public

Answer (score 6):

In XCode 7, you can include internal ivars with a line:
    @testable import 
No need to make the ivars public if you want to keep them conceiled from the outside world...